# "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" on Hill-RSA cryptography

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, hill-climbing

I'm trying to code a *Hill-RSA* cryptography program that you can see a part of here:

```
q2=31
alphabet=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",","," ",".",";","_"]
X=np.zeros((m,1),dtype=np.int32)
Y=np.zeros((m,1),dtype=np.int32)
Texte_decode="";
for i in range(1,(len(Texte_code)/m)+1):
    for k in range(0,m):
        j=0
        while (Texte_code[k+m*(i-1)]<>alphabet[j+1]):
            j=j+1
        X[k]=j
    X=X.transpose()
    A2=np.zeros((m,m),dtype=np.int32)
    for u in range(0,m):
        for l in range(0,m):
            A2[u,l]=A[u,l]
    Y=X.dot(A2)
    Y=Y.transpose()
    pprint(Y)
    Y2=np.zeros((m,1),dtype=np.int32)
    for ind in range(0,m):
        Y2[ind]=Y[ind]%q2
    pprint(Y2)
    for k in range(0,m):
        Texte_decode=Texte_decode+alphabet[Y2[k]+1]
for i in range(len(Texte_decode),len(Texte_decode)-m+1,-1):
    if Texte_decode[i]=="." and Texte_decode[i-1]==".":
        Texte_decode=Texte_decode[1,i-1]
print Texte_decode
```

When i execute this part, I get

> "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

on the line

```
Texte_decode=Texte_decode+alphabet[Y2[k]+1]
```

Can anyone help me get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What debugging have you done?  Did you review the nature of the elements of the problem line?

```
Texte_decode=Texte_decode+alphabet[Y2[k]+1]
```

`k` comes from `for k in range(0,m):` so that shouldn't be the problem.  It's clearly an integer.

Your printed `Y2`.  It's initialed as a `(m,1)` array.  So `Y2[k]` will be a (1,) array, right?

`alphabet` is a list.

In an interactive shell let's try a test case:

```
In [70]: [1,2,3,4][np.array([1])]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-4ad73b219fa3> in <module>()
----> 1 [1,2,3,4][np.array([1])]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Same error message!

If we start with a 1d array, and select an element, the indexing works:

```
In [71]: [1,2,3,4][np.arange(4)[1]]
Out[71]: 2
```

Now that we understand the problem, the solution should be obvious, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your answer. m is declared before and is equal to 5, which makes Y2 a (1,5) array

Comment: `Y2=np.zeros((m,1),dtype=np.int32)`

Comment: This is how I declared Y2. What improvment do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Explain why you chose to initial `Y2` with that shape? What's different in my 2 test examples?

Comment: So I was supposed to translate a Maple code to python and that's how I figured it would work. Here is the original code if you want to look at it [link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/YxZD9n9GLPcv-DFKjG5-eQ4JBUMntkSUUMQF9z3jbnVuEJaXYHL1LJixZKLS9L0ZHui37SkV5cAbRNUQPfr0=w1920-h944)

Comment: I don't need to know what the Maple code is supposed to do.  We are dealing with a simple `numpy` case here.  If you are going to get anywhere with Python/numpy coding you need to understand it's `shape` and `indexing` approaches.  The difference between `np.zeros((m,1), int)` and `np.zeros(m, int)` matters in this situation.  Do you know how to test Python code in an interactive session?  I can't code `numpy` without window open where I can test bits and pieces of the code to verify that they work.  I tried to illustrate that in my answer.